# URLSession image download crash - Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession, kingfisher

I am using URLSession to download image and mapping to the image item imageview. But getting crash on below line always. I tried using Kingfisher, but still getting crash on same line

URLSession :

```
 class ImageFetchOperation: AsyncOperation {
    let imageItem: ImageItem
    let session: URLSession
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    var menuImageView: UIImageView!
    init(imageItem:ImageItem, session:URLSession) {
        self.imageItem = imageItem
        self.session = session
    }
    
    override func main() {
        
        
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: self.imageItem.imageUrl) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: imageUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            //request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
            //print(imageUrl)
            dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                guard !(self?.isCancelled)! else {
                    self?.state = .isFinished
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    self?.state = .isFinished
                    return
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self?.imageItem.image = UIImage.init(data:data) // Getting crash here
                }
                self?.state = .isFinished

            })
            dataTask?.resume()
        }
        else {
            self.state = .isFinished
        }
   
    }
}
```

Kingfisher

```
  if let imageUrl = self.imageItem.imageUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.menuImageView = UIImageView()
            let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
            self.menuImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            self.menuImageView!.kf.setImage(with: url, completionHandler:  { [weak self] (image, error, cache, url) in
                self?.imageItem.image = image // Getting crash here
                self?.state = .isFinished
            })
        }

    }
```

In both code getting crash on :

```
   self?.imageItem.image = UIImage.init(data:data)

   self?.imageItem.image = image
```

Any help would be great here.

**Crash : Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2600010c)**

**Image URL is proper only:**

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg

[Crash image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW6XZ.png)

```
@objcMembers class ImageItem: NSObject {
    let imageUrl: String
    dynamic var image: UIImage!

    init(imageUrl: String) {
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
        self.image = nil
    }
    init(imageName: String) {
        self.imageUrl = ""
        self.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for `imageItem`

Comment: In `ImageFetchOperation`, you have `let imageItem: ImageItem`, try `var imageItem: ImageItem`. The compiler should have warn you of this. Also do not use `self?`, use `self`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine sure  thanks will change it. 

But still crash is happening for first 4 to 5 time on fresh install build. After 5th time crash is not happening

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine crash screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW6XZ.png

Comment: cannot replicate your crashes. All works well for me in my simple tests, with the modifications I mentioned, no `self?`. Note, you are using code from the dark ages, there are more modern ways to fetch an image with just a few lines of code, such as using Swift async/await concurrency framework.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine But inside operation queue its forcing me to add either ? or !
 OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                        self?.imageItem.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

Comment: ok, I was using my test `AsyncOperation`, maybe you need it in there. How about Vladimir answer, does it not work for you?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Its same as my code only. But getting this crash every time. I that could be an xcode issues. i am using 13.4.1 version

Comment: could be the Xcode version, or a 101 other things. I'm on 14.1-beta2 with macos Ventura 13.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your whole code, please? I tried to reproduce your code and it worked for me. Here is what I tried:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum State {
    case isFinished
    case isCancelled
}

struct Image {
    var imageUrl: String
    var image: UIImage?
    
    init(imageUrl: String, image: UIImage?) {
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.image = image
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var isCancelled: Bool = false
    var state: State?
    var imageItem = Image(imageUrl: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg", image: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: self.imageItem.imageUrl) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: imageUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            //request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
            //print(imageUrl)
            dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                guard !(self?.isCancelled)! else {
                    self?.state = .isFinished
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    self?.state = .isFinished
                    return
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    self?.imageItem.image = UIImage.init(data:data) // Getting crash here
                    if let image = self?.imageItem.image {
                        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                        self?.view.addSubview(imageView)
                        
                        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                        
                        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self?.view.centerXAnchor)!),
                            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self?.view.centerYAnchor)!),
                        ])
                    }
                }
                self?.state = .isFinished

            })
            dataTask?.resume()
        }
        else {
            self.state = .isFinished
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my full code